# Null value checking of an object inside an object inside an object

Tags: c#

If I do:

```
var a = FirstPossibleNull.SecondPossibleNull.ThirdPossibleNull.FourthPossibleNullValue;
```

I'd have to check if "FirstPossibleNull" and "SecondPossibleNull" and 'ThirdPossibleNull" is not null to avoid running in a potential error.

Is there a more elegant (and shorter) solution than this sort of check:

```
if (FirstPossibleNull != null && FirstPossibleNull.SecondPossibleNull != null && FirstPossibleNull.SecondPossibleNull.ThirdPossibleNull != null)
```

Comment: I think it is the best  approach! :D

Comment: Not yet but it's coming: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Comment: It might be argued that if you've got a particular bit of code that's accessing properties that deep, it might need to be refactored.